# Lock a SQL Server 2008 database during use

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking

I have a document processing application that runs as a service and can be configured to use a local or network database. Is there a way to ensure that the database remain locked as long as the service is running? By locked I mean, the user should not be able to delete or revoke access to the database without shutting down the service first.

Comment: I don't know of one. But is that the best way to approach the problem? Wouldn't it be better to use shadow tables for the Document processing so that the main database can remain available, but the Document processing can proceed on it's "snapshot" of data? Obviously, all this depends on the size/amount of data involved.

Comment: The amount of data being generated is massive. The database is dedicated to this application and data is exported only after post-processing tabulation is complete. The idea was to prevent the user from interrupting the process until it is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, I can't help with this. I don't know that it is possible to lock the entire database and prevent others access to it while a process is running.

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682(v=sql.105).aspx) for setting the database to single-user mode.  `ALTER DATABASE ThineDb SINGLE_USER`.

Comment: It seems there is no reliable solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual scenario. I have never done this.

However, I think it is possible. What you need to do is to create a second instance of the SQL Server and use for the background processing.

Before the processing begins you need to detach the database from the main instance and attach it to the background. Do all the processing on the background instance while the database is detached from the main instance and attached to the background.

After you have done, re-attach the database back to the main instance.

The detaching and attaching can be easily done via transact SQL. Read this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx)